# Undefined class 'AllCoursesSnapshot'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database and display it on my UI. This is the code written :

```
class AllCourses {
  String courseName;
  String teacher;
  String category;

  AllCourses(this.courseName, this.teacher, this.category);
}
```

```
import 'package:creators_club/firestore/courses.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BusinessPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BusinessPageState createState() => _BusinessPageState();
}

class _BusinessPageState extends State<BusinessPage> {
  List<AllCourses> coursesList = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    DatabaseReference referenceAllCourses = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('AllCourses');
    referenceAllCourses.once().then(((AllCoursesSnapshot allCoursesSnapshot){
      coursesList.clear();
      var keys = allCoursesSnapshot.value.keys;
      var values = allCoursesSnapshot.value;
      for(var key in keys){
        AllCourses allCourses = new AllCourses(
          values [key]["courseName"],
          values [key]["teacher"],
          values [key]["category"],
        );
        coursesList.add(allCourses);
      }
      setState(() {
        //HERE
      });
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),),
          title: Text("Creator's Club"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff2657ce),
          elevation: 0,),
        body: coursesList.length == 0 ? Center(child: Text("No Data Avail", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)): ListView.builder(
          itemCount: coursesList.length,
            itemBuilder: (_,index){
              return CardUI(coursesList[index].courseName, coursesList[index].teacher, coursesList[index].category);}
            )
    );
  }
}
}
```

Why isn't the AllCoursesSnapshot being recognized? It says that it is "Type: Null Function(dynamic)".
Here is a picture of the database table in Realtime Database: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R8sK.jpg).

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recognized because there is no class called `AllCoursesSnapshot`. The `once()` method belongs to the `firebase_database` plugin, and it returns a `Future<DataSnapshot>`, therefore you have to do the following:

```
referenceAllCourses.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
```

Also replace `allCoursesSnapshot` with `dataSnapshot` in the other parts of your code.